# How can use SPDK in tcpdump?

Tags: intel, tcpdump

How do I make **tcpdump** to use **SPDK**(Storage Performance Development Kit) to write on my storage devices such as hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

By cloning the tcpdump and libpcap source code from the Git repository and modifying the file writing/reading code for libpcap to leverage SPDK.

Comment: I know that tcpdump uses libpcap to capture network packets but don't know does it write them itself? (tcpdump source code contains any type of writers?), or it uses libpcap to write captured packet on file. I have been finding out from your answer that tcpdump uses libpcap to write on file. Am I right? Note: I checked out both source codes of libpcap and tcpdump to clear aforementioned problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the code yet?  No, tcpdump uses the libpcap library for all file and packet access.